# Rubygems. LoadError in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Everytime I start my Rails applications I get **LoadError** with the following output.

On Rails 2.3.8:

```
no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
```

On Rails 3.0.0:

```
no such file to load -- bundler
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
```

I run the applications in the production mode on a development machine using Nginx + Passenger.

What is the reason of this issue? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.6;

Ruby 1.9.2;

Rubygems 1.3.7;

Ruby on Rails 2.3.8, 3.0.0;

Nginx 0.8.50;

Passenger 2.2.15;

sqlite3-ruby 1.3.1;

bundler 1.0.0.rc.6.

**Updated**

---

All of my gems is installed by the unprivileged user in the local directory `/home/<usernam>/.gem`. If it helps, here's the `gem env` output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/<username>/.gem
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/<username>/.gem/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/<username>/.gem
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
     - :gemhome => "/home/<username>/.gem"
     - :gempath => ["/home/<username>/.gem"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

**Updated**

---

I tackled with the problem. Its source was that **I defined a custom gem path**. That is I added to the `~/.gemrc` file the following lines:

```
:gemhome: /home/<username>/.gem
:gempaths:
  - /home/<username>/.gem
```

Thus all of my gems was placed in the specified directory but not the default one. For some reason Rubygems coundn't find it there and rose an exception.

When I removed that lines from the file the default paths was set for Rubygems and after I installed all the required gems and loaded my Rails applications all began to work.

Once again, the bug conditions are:

1. Nginx + Passenger;
2. The gempath is set to `/home/<unprivileged_user>/.gem` in `~/.gemrc`;
3. An `init.d` script is creaded and added to the boot sequence (`update-rc.d nginx defaults`);
4. System is rebooted, server is started atomaticlally;
5. http://localhost/my_rails_app;
6. LoadError; no such file to load -- <gem_name>; <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'.

**Why can't Rubygems find gems in the custom location but can find them in default?** That's the question.

Answer (score 2):

I too had this problem when using RVM - I must have specified a gemset or something and not made it project specific.  At any rate, read this [rvm guide](http://ascarter.net/2010/05/30/ruby-version-manager.html) if you want to know the basics of RVM and try to specify a new gemset for your current folder / project, install a new rails gem to that gemset, and then use that gemset. For example, to create a new gemset for rails version 2.3.8:

---

$ rvm gemset create rails238

---

$ rvm ruby-1.8.7@rails238

---

$ gem install rails -v 2.3.8

---

Then if all went according to plan type rvm gemset use [gemsetName], or do rvm gemset list to see a list of installed gemsets, and to see if rails is working fine try rails -v and you should see rails 2.3.8

Comment: The OP has not indicated they are using RVM. It's not always possible to use RVM on a production server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your system to locate where your rubies and gems are installed ( you can do this by "which ruby" and "which gem"). Usually, they're installed in the same folder (/usr/bin or /usr/local). If they are in different locations, there might be load error. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Sudo has nothing to do with installing, and nothing in here implies that he is using a system that uses sudo (ie Ubuntu, since most others use su).

Comment: They're at the same folder (`/usr/local/bin`).